# Changing Git Location on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, git, path, bashrc

I have a version of Git (1.9.3) already installed on my computer at `/usr/bin`. This version was installed (if I remember correctly) by XCode. I would like to install 2.2.1 (the download version from http://git-scm.com). I can install it fine with the executable at `/usr/local/git/bin`.

The problem is that I have putting the new path at both the beginning and end of $PATH, but `which git` always returns `/usr/bin/git` and `git --version` remains `1.9.3`. My `/usr/local/git/bin` section is added as expected to the beginning or end of the whole path.

I am using hub from Github with `hub alias` being executed, but I cannot get git to update even if I comment hub out of my `.bashrc`.

Comment: What's the output from `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Forgot to add that, thanks! Edited in above, but when I try to prepend/append it to path, it shows up as expected, but the old git is used regardless of the new one being added to the beginning or the end.